# Need to sum the numbers 1 through 100, how to write a loop to complete the operation?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm learning Lua from a book and this is the exact question I'm stuck on:

> Given that you need to sum the numbers 1 through 100, write a loop to complete the operation.

I've tried various things, but my most recent attempt following:

```
n = 1
while (n < 100) do
    n = n + 1
    print (n)
end
```

Comment: How come no answer accepted? Did none help? Then comments or clarification may save this.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned earlier, you need at least two variables: one to hold sum and second to count to 100.

Fixed steps calculations is better to do with [for](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html) loop.

```
local sum = 0
for i = 1, 100 do
  sum = sum + i
end
print(sum)
```

P.S. Where is the question? Add not only broken code, but some words about what is wrong with it please.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you need to do something like this:

```
local n = 1
local sum = 0
while (n <= 100) do
  sum = sum + n
  n = n + 1
end
print(sum)
```

It should help if you keep your sum and counter in separate variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need another variable to hold the sum :)
I believe this should do it:

```
i=0
n=0
while i <= 100 do
n = i + n
i = i + 1
end
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are visible after they their first assignment. So you need one variable declared outside the loop to hold the sum as it is updated inside the loop, like this:

```
n = 0
sum = 0
while (n < 100) do
    n = n + 1 -- n variable output is 1,2,3,4,5,...100
    sum = sum + n -- sum variable remembers its value from previous iteration
    print (sum)
end
```

When you do sum = sum + n, the interpreter takes the current value of sum, adds n to it, and puts the result into sum. At next iteration, sum still has that most recent value. Compare, if you had done

```
while (n < 100) do
    n = n + 1 -- n variable output is 1,2,3,4,5,...100
    local sum = sum + n -- sum is "new" at every iteration so fails
    print (sum)
end
```

This sum variable is local to loop so every time through loop, a new sum is created. Only problem is,

```
local sum = sum + n
```

that statement tries to get value of "sum" and add it to n, but sum is being created on that line so it doesn't exist yet so interpreter will throw error about attempt to do arithmetic on global "sum" (the sum that appears on right hand side is not know to compiler so it thinks it is a global since it hasn't created the local sum yet).

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers ignore that sum can be calculated using a single equation;

Assume largest number is "N"

Sum of integers from 1 to N is; ( N x ( N + 1 )) / 2